# What is 「オンギャー」?

Tags: onomatopoeia

It is doubtless onomatopoeia, and shows up in a version of the story about a woman ghost who buys candy for a child each night. What does it represent?

Answer (score 4):

オギャー or オンギャー is a baby's crying sound, especially a sound at the moment when a baby was born. We are relieved when we hear the sound at the moment because the baby was born healthy.
オギャー is used more than オンギャー.
[Here](https://www.englishforums.com/English/BabysCryingSound/jvvgp/post.htm) in [here](https://nolan00267.blogspot.jp/2015/03/blog-post_50.html) you can find the equivalent sound in English as "**waa** or **waaah**".

Comment: @naruto: そのようにします。ところで過去形was bornで良いのでしょうか。迷っています。

Comment: そこは個人的には問題ないと思いますが自信ないです。まあ伝わるはず！ｗ